# ClassCastException On Action When Invoked From Specs2

Tags: scala, playframework, specs2

I'm building an application on **play_2.9.1-2.0.3** and testing with **specs2_2.9.1-1.7.1** (which came bundled with play). I have an action that looks like this:

```
def createPoll() = Action { request =>
    request.body.asJson.map {jsonBod =>
        Poll.fromJsonValue(jsonBod).fold(
            thrown => CommonResponses.invalidCreatePollRequest(this),
            poll => (CommonResponses.createdPoll(poll, this))
    )}.getOrElse(CommonResponses.expectingJson(this))
}
```

This works as expected when I send it a message from curl, but in my specs2 test I get this exception:

```
ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to play.api.mvc.AnyContent(PollController.scala:16)
```

where line 16 is:

```
def createPoll() = Action { request =>
```

Here is the relevant part of the test:

```
    routeAndCall(
        FakeRequest(
            PUT, controllers.routes.PollController.createPoll().url,
            FakeHeaders(),
            "{\"userId\":\"%s\",\"title\":\"%s\"}".format(userId, title)
        ).withHeaders(("Content-type", "application/json"))
    )
```

If I change the `createPoll` def to: `def createPoll() = Action(parse.tolerantText) {`

then I can make it work from the specs2 test.

**Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?** Ideally I would like to use the parse.json body parser but I want to be able to use specs and not just curl for testing. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The apply method on Action takes a `Request[AnyContent] => Result`. The parametrized type of the FakeRequest is the type of the fourth parameter (the body of the request). Given these, the problem is quite obvious: you're trying to pass a `Request[String]` as an input to a function that takes a `Request[AnyContent]`. Hence the class cast exception. All you need to do is create a FakeRequest with an `AnyContentAsJson` (A subtype of `AnyContent`) like this:

```
import play.api.libs.json.Json.parse

FakeRequest(
        PUT, controllers.routes.PollController.createPoll().url,
        FakeHeaders(),
        AnyContentAsJson(parse("{\"userId\":\"%s\",\"title\":\"%s\"}".format(userId, title)))
    )
```

Comment: Oh, that makes perfect sense! Thanks very much for responding